# Customize object debug popup info Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, tostring, android-debug

When I'm in debug mode and hover over a variable of most object types, I get relevant information.

For example, a string type shows me the text of the string:

[image: s_working]

But for objects of my own custom type, I just get the object type and a number:

[image: p_fail]

I've overridden the toString method, which I thought ought to work:

[image: p_toString]

It does show up correctly in the "object tree" when I click the popup:

[image: p_objecttree]

And printing the object or calling toString works:

[image: p_watches]

How can I control the text in first popup when I hover over an object of my type? Bonus points of your solution also eliminates the stuff between the curly braces in my last two pictures.

Answer (score 0):

See how to [customize data type renderers](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/customize-data-views.html) in IntelliJ.

Comment: This is helpful for some things. To get rid of most of the stuff between the curly braces leaving only the type ({CardPoint}), go to settings > Debugger > Data Views and uncheck "Fully qualified names" and "Object id"

Comment: But even though I have toString enabled, that only seems to affect what is shown in the Object Tree view (after clicking the tooltip). The first popup still doesn't call toString, even if I add it as an expression in the Data Type Renderers tab. Any further suggestions?